# Static Android homescreen widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, homescreen, appwidgetprovider

I´ve developed an android application with it´s own widget.

To bring the widget in the right form, I set minWidth to 300dp and minHeight to 400 dp.

When placing it to the homescreen, it has the right dimensions, but anyway, it´s possible to resize it into any form you want, even 1x1 cells, which should be prevented by setting minWidth and minHeight.

How could you make the widget non-resizable?

Answer (score 0):

in your widget properties, set **android:resizeMode="none"**

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="60000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: doesn´t work for me. he does not know resizeMode. error:no resource identifier found for attribute 'resizeMode' in package 'android'

Comment: okay, now I´ve testet it again, but it is still resizing, target sdk 12, min sdk 12, build sdk 17. I don´t get it